# Optimal choice for the values of money units

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, discrete-optimization

I just thought about how to find the optimal values for money units, given that you want your currency to come in $n$ different values (e.g. Euros come in 7 values for bills and 8 values for coins, so 15 values all together).

Fix a set $A\subseteq{\bf N}_{\ge 1}$ of size $n$ with $1\in A$ which represents all values your currency comes in (for simplicity I assume that there exist only coins and your currency has only values in the natural numbers, so no e.g. Eurocents).  Let $f(A,k)$ denote the minimum number $j$ such there exist $a_1,\dots,a_j\in A$ with $\sum_i a_i=k$, i.e. we can do a payment of value $k$ using $f(A,k)$ coins.  Further fix a discrete distribution $P:{\bf N}_{\ge 1}\rightarrow{\bf R}_{\ge 0}$ which denotes the probability that a random payment is of value $n$.  Then let $g(A,P)=\sum_i P(i)f(A,i)$ be the expected value of the number of coins you need to do a random payment.

Are there reasonable values known for $n$ and $P$ (e.g. $P$ equals the geometric distribution) such that we can find an $A$ which minimizes $g(A,P)$, and if yes, is $A$ unique?

Comment: I don't know about the probabilistic approach, but the optimal currency values are powers of two.
Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152178/ideal-coin-value-choices?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link, they mentioned [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/change2.pdf) paper which I found quite interesting.  But it's still different from my question because they are only interested in representing values as coins up to a given limit, typically the value of the smallest bill.  I don't make that assumption, also I can't use uniform distribution therefore.